# Change HTML source in winforms

Tags: html, vb.net, winforms

I have the below structure for a html page

```
<video controls="controls" width="480" height="208" id="video1">
        <source src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/2642/sintel-trailer.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
        <source src="http://devfiles.myopera.com/articles/2642/sintel-trailer.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
</video>
```

There is no problem in the above code.  I need to replace the `src` of the video with the one I select from the local resource (i.e.from desktop or any other folder) using `OpenfileDialog` and replace the filename with its extension in place of `src="http://"`. For example, if `mymovie.mp4` was selected I would read the html template file and replace the src tag of that video with `mymovie.mp4`.

So how do I modify it?

Answer (score 0):

I think either a regex could work here:

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(inputString, _
                 @"<source src=\"(.*?)\"", _
                 RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

If (m.Success) Then
        ' Loop through each group (which will contain the href value)
        ' Open with that href and just do a replace on the original string
        ' m.Groups(1).Value
End If
```

Or, you could load the html into an XmlDocument and replace it that way.

```
Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
Dim m_node As XmlNode

' Create the XML Document
m_xmld = New XmlDocument()

' Load the Xml file
m_xmld.Load("html string here")

' Get the list of name nodes 
m_nodelist = m_xmld.SelectNodes(@"//video/source")

For Each m_node In m_nodelist
' Get the attribute value
Dim srcValue = m_node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("src").Value

' Load the value and store new value
' Replace the attribute with the new
m_node.Attributes.SetNamedItem(NEWVALUE)

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript like this:
1. Change your html code:

```
<video id="myVideo" controls="controls" width="480" height="208" id="video1">
```

2. Implement this functions:

```
function gid(id){
    var d=document;
    if(d.getElementById){
        return d.getElementById(id);
    }
    else if(d.all){
        return d.all[id];
    }
    else if(d.layers){
        return d.layers[id];
    }
    return null;
}
function changeVideoContent(){
    var content = '<source src="http://... and all you desire...';
    gid("myVideo").innerHTML  = content;
}
```

3. Bind changeVideoContent function with your form using onSubmit, onClick or other events.